# Connect interface with Google Cloud Shell

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell, google-cloud-shell-editor

I have the next situation, I hope you can help me to solve this problem.

I need to create an interface that need to connected with Google Cloud Shell.
I need to write a command in the app and this need to be send to the Google Shell, but I don't know how to connect this and I don't find information about it.

An example can be
I write the next command to obtain information about gcloud topic:

gcloud help topic

And show the result in my web, without use or write the command directly on the Google Cloud Shell.
My web app is created with react and I want to send the command and show the results in the app, but I don't know how to connect with the Google Cloud Shell.

I hope you can help me, I'm so lost with this task, if I can give you more information, tell me.

Have a great day!

Comment: I wrote a program with an extensive interface to Cloud Shell written in Go. This will show you many features that you can use to develop your own app. https://github.com/jhanley-com/google-cloud-shell-cli-go

Comment: Thank you, I'm gonna check your information, thank you so much